# How a Switch creates a separate Collision Network on each port?

Tags: networking

While going through a CCNA book,i found that switch creates separate collision network on each port.Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repeater (hub) is a device that unconditionally forwards packets - or rather single bits/symbols - from one of its ports to all the others. For this, the other ports have to be idle. There can only be a single transmission at any one time. Collisions that happen anywhere must be propagated to the other ports. All ports form a single collision domain.

A switch (bridge) conditionally forwards packets (frames) based on their destination address to the port that address is connected to. For this, they receive the frame (store), examine the destination address and forward the frame to the port associated with the address.

This process requires them to buffer the frame - this in turn enables the switch to receive a frame from one port while the destination port may or may not be idle. The destination port may just be transmitting a frame or experiencing a collision, without this having any impact on the reception from the source port. The frame from the source port is received, forwarding is decided. If the destination port is busy at this time, the switch just waits for the port to become idle and then forwards the buffered frame.

This buffering and queueing makes propagation of collision events from one port to the others completely useless. Therefore, a switch divides a network into separate collision domains, one on each of its port.

Note that all this only applies to half-duplex communication. For a good while, full-duplex communication has been the standard. In full-duplex mode, a port can receive and transmit simultaneously, and no collisions ever happen.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of Gigabit Ethernet switch ports, full-duplex operation was the default where data could transmit in both directions simultaneously. That effectively doubles the bandwidth to your desktop and switch - switch connections. There are no collisions possible on a properly configured Gigabit switch port that has no hardware defects on the link to desktop or another switch as a result. There is a single collision domain created with each Gigabit port. Should a collision occur for the reasons mentioned it is isolated to that single network connection (domain) and does not affect neighbor connections.